# function "get_header" doesn't work in certain pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a beginner coder working on a WordPress website and have come across a critical error: I have created a header.php file and tried using the get_header() function to import the header into all of my pages. In my index.php page, it works perfectly, but in all of my other pages, I get an error message saying “Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()”. For experimental purposes, the code in my "index.php" page is the same as in all of my other ".php" pages. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code for one of my pages “feedback.php”:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Import Header from header.php -->
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Basic Responsivness -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title> Home </title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Notable&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<style type="text/css">

h2 {
font-family: 'Notable', sans-serif;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2> Hello World </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the ' ; '. Use `get_header();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using [wordpress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) wrong. I had the same problem this week, same as you I didn't understood why it doesn't work on other pages.

You should add pages manually from wordpress dashboard (for example, add about page).

Name the file locally as page-about.php (basically, page-{slug}).

Afterwards try accessing it like this: `www.example.com/about/` or `www.example.com/?page-id={id}` ({id} is your page id, can be found at wordpress dashboard).

Comment: @WireWordPress It's just to sync the wordpress system with your theme files. basically you create page in the dashboard and the theme files as I said and edit the page in your theme files.